# what is the punishment for missing 1 prayer

Tags: salat

what should i do if i stayed up until after fajr and when the time came i didn’t make wudu until a hour passed so there was 1 hour left when i made wudu, i was about to pray my mom woke up and i talked to her while i was lying down in my bed so when she went to sleep i’m pretty sure i fell asleep and missed fajr because i can’t remember praying it, what should i do?
(my mom doesn’t pray so don’t say why didn’t you pray with her)

Comment: Why should there always be a punishment? If you missed it make it up once you remember it. And repent and try to avoid delaying prayers.

Comment: but i had the chance to pray and i delayed it and fell asleep is it true i just need to repent and make it up? also if i missed prayers in the past do i have to make them up now because i made up most of them but i don’t know if i didn’t make up a couple thanks

Comment: Please do some prior research before asking questions. You may even find answers on our site.

Answer (score 1):

You pray anyway, even if it's too late. It's like having a missing assignment, do you just leave it? No. You do it anyway and turn it in. And remember Allah is the Most Merciful, as long as you ask for forgiveness and make up for your prayers, you should be fine InshaAllah. Also here's a tip,  when you wake up for Fajr immediately get out of your bed, go to wudu with COLD water and pray, do not go back on your bed until you prayed. But anyway, remember it's VERY important to pray your prayers on time:

“Whoever prays the dawn prayer in congregation, it is as if he had prayed the whole night long.” (Muslim, p. 454, no. 656; al-Tirmidhi, 221).

The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) also said:

“The most burdensome prayers for the hypocrites are salaat al-’isha’ and salaat al-fajr, but if they only knew what they contain, they would come even if they had to crawl.” (Reported by Imaam Ahmad, al-Musnad, 2/424; Saheeh al-Jaami’, 133).

“Whoever prays fajr is under the protection of Allah. Do not put yourselves in a situation where Allah has to call you to account for your negligence.” (Reported by al-Tabaraani, 7/267; Saheeh al-Jaami’, no. 6344).

“Angels come to you in shifts by night and by day. They meet at salaat al-fajr and salaat al-‘asr, then those who had stayed with you at night ascend, and are asked by the One Who knows better than they: ‘How did you find My servants?’ They say, ‘We left them when they were praying, and we came to them when they were praying.’” (Reported by al-Bukhaari, al-Fath, 2/33).

“The best of prayers in the sight of Allah is the dawn prayer on Friday, in congregation.” (Reported by Abu Na’eem in al-Hilyah, 7/207, and in al-Silsilah al-Saheehah, 1566).

According to a saheeh hadeeth:

“Whoever prays al-Bardayn will enter Paradise.” (Reported by al-Bukhaari, al-Fath, 2/52). Al-Bardayn are fajr and ‘asr.

Also I tried my best with this answer, so please if anyone sees any mistakes don't downvote just comment or edit it.